# find a word within a text file that contains certain characters and is a specific length

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find words within a text file that are of 7 letters in length and contain the letters a, b, c, e and r. So far I have this:

```
import re

file = open("dictionary.txt","r")
text = file.readlines()
file.close()


keyword = re.compile(r'\w{7}')

for line in text:
    result = keyword.search (line)
    if result:
       print (result.group())
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does the word contain *only* the letters `a`, `b`, `c`, `e` and `r` or must it contain *at least* those letters?

Comment: @Becs1990 You should get in the habit of marking the answer that solves your problem by clicking the checkmark underneat the vote.

Answer (score 2):

You need to not only match the word characters, but also the word *boundary*:

```
keyword = re.compile(r'\b\w{7}\b')
```

The `\b` anchor matches at the start or end of a word, limiting the word to *exactly* 7 characters.

It'd be more efficient if you were to loop through the file line-by-line instead of reading it all into memory in one go:

```
import re

keyword = re.compile(r'\b\w{7}\b')

with open("dictionary.txt","r") as dictionary:    
    for line in dictionary:
        for result in keyword.findall(line):
            print(result)
```

Using `keyword.findall()` gives us a list of *all* matches on the line.

To check if the matches have at least one of the required characters in it, I personally would just use a set intersection test:

```
import re

keyword = re.compile(r'\b\w{7}\b')
required = set('abcer')

with open("dictionary.txt","r") as dictionary:    
    for line in dictionary:
        results = [required.intersection(word) for word in keyword.findall(line)]
        for result in results
            print(result)
```

Comment: That won't return anything from the file. The words returned can contain any or all of those letters. I am so confused.

Comment: @Becs1990: please add some example words that should match to your question then.

Comment: There are 24,000 words in total in my dictionary. But for example: abalone
abandon
abbrevi
abdicat
abdomen
abdomin
Abelian
Abelson
Aberdee
Abernat

Comment: @Becs1990: You need to be clearer as to what the letters `a`, `b`, `c`, `e` and `r` have to do with this. Does a valid word have *at least one* of those 5 letters in it?

Comment: Yes, each word needs to contain at least one of those characters. Sorry for being a nuisance!

Answer (score 1):

```
\b(?=\w{0,6}?[abcer])\w{7}\b
```

That's the regular expression you want.  It works by using the basic form for a word of exactly seven letters (`\b\w{7}\b`) and adding a lookahead - a zero width assertion that looks forward and tries to find one of your required letters.  A breakdown:

```
\b            A word boundary
(?=           Look ahead and find...
    \w        A word character (A-Za-z0-9_)
    {0,6}     Repeated 0 to 6 times
    ?         Lazily (not necessary, but marginally more efficient).
    [abcer]   Followed by one of a, b, c, e, or r
)             Go back to where we were before (just after the word boundary
\w            And match a word character
{7}           Exactly seven times.
\b            Then one more word Boundary.
```